# Missing site templates when creating a publising (template) site in SP2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

All I am  having issues trying to add some of the additional site templates when a user selects New Site form the site settings menu.  I have a publishing site template as recomended by Microsoft as a default Intranet site.  How can I add some of the templates such as a team site, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using a publishing template from the start, so i rebuilt the server anyway, and created a blank site with activitating the publishing features.